# Don't know where to place saveData to save data with userDefaults in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to save my data after being changed by the user, the thing im saving the data from my model also im fetching the data from my model class, I would like to save the data once the viewwilldissappear so all the data will be saved and I can fetch the data from my model(when I init it again), I kinda lost the way with implementing it :\
Here's my VC Code: where i set up my tableView cells + would like to use saveData() there:

```
import UIKit
import PanModal


class FilterTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, PanModalPresentable {
    
    //Instance of our ViewModel
    private var filterViewModel = FilterViewModel()
    
    //Our Model Instance:
//    private var filterModel = FilterModel()

    let tableView = UITableView()
    var safeArea: UILayoutGuide!
    let buttonView = UIView()
    
    var panScrollable: UIScrollView? {
        return tableView
    }
    
    
    var albumsPickerIndexPath: IndexPath? //  indexPath of the currently shown albums picker in tableview.
    //    var delegate: FilterTableViewDelegate?
    
    
    var datesCell = DatesCell()
    var selectedAlbumByUser = ""
    
    
    //    var userFilter: FilterModel?
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        safeArea = view.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        setupTableView()
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        setupButtonView()
    }
    
    
    
    
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
    
    
    
    // MARK: - Views Configurations
    
    func setupTableView() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor,constant: 120).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        
        
        tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
        tableView.allowsSelection = true
        
        
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600
        
        
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        
    }
    
    
    func setupButtonView() {
        
        view.addSubview(buttonView)
        buttonView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        buttonView.backgroundColor = .white
        buttonView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
        //        buttonView.clipsToBounds  =  true
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            buttonView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.bottomAnchor),
            buttonView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.bottomAnchor,constant: 10),
            buttonView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor,constant: 16),
            buttonView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor,constant: -16),
            buttonView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            buttonView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
        ])
        
        
        let applyFiltersButton = UIButton()
        applyFiltersButton.setTitle("Apply Filters", for: .normal)
        applyFiltersButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        applyFiltersButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
        //        myFirstButton.clipsToBounds  =  true
        applyFiltersButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1957295239, green: 0.6059523225, blue: 0.960457623, alpha: 1)
        applyFiltersButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center;
        applyFiltersButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:16)
        
        
        self.buttonView.addSubview(applyFiltersButton)
        applyFiltersButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            applyFiltersButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.topAnchor),
            applyFiltersButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.bottomAnchor),
            applyFiltersButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.leadingAnchor),
            applyFiltersButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.trailingAnchor),
            applyFiltersButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            applyFiltersButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            applyFiltersButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.centerXAnchor),
            applyFiltersButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.centerYAnchor)
            
        ])
    }
    
    
    func indexPathToInsertDatePicker(indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath {
        if let albumsPickerIndexPath = albumsPickerIndexPath, albumsPickerIndexPath.row < indexPath.row {
            return indexPath
        } else {
            return IndexPath(row: indexPath.row + 1, section: indexPath.section)
        }
    }
    
    
    
    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // If datePicker is already present, we add one extra cell for that
        if albumsPickerIndexPath != nil {
            return 5 + 1
        } else {
            return 5
        }
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            
            let byActivityCell = UINib(nibName: "byActivityCell",bundle: nil)
            self.tableView.register(byActivityCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "byActivityCell")
            let activityCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "byActivityCell", for: indexPath) as! byActivityCell
            activityCell.selectionStyle = .none
            activityCell.activityDelegate = filterViewModel
            
            
            return activityCell
            
        case 1:
            let byTypeCell = UINib(nibName: "ByType",bundle: nil)
            self.tableView.register(byTypeCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "byTypeCell")
            let typeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "byTypeCell", for: indexPath) as! ByType
            typeCell.selectionStyle = .none
            typeCell.byTypeDelegate = filterViewModel
            
            
            return typeCell
            
            
        case 2:
            let byHashtagsCell = UINib(nibName: "ByHashtags",bundle: nil)
            self.tableView.register(byHashtagsCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "byHashtagsCell")
            let hashtagsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "byHashtagsCell", for: indexPath) as! ByHashtags
            hashtagsCell.selectionStyle = .none
            hashtagsCell.byHashtagsDelegate = filterViewModel
            
            return hashtagsCell
            
        case 3:
            let byDatesCell = UINib(nibName: "DatesCell",bundle: nil)
            self.tableView.register(byDatesCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "byDatesCell")
            let datesCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "byDatesCell", for: indexPath) as! DatesCell
            datesCell.selectionStyle = .none
            datesCell.datesTableViewCellDelegate = self
            
            
            
            return datesCell
            
            
        case 4:
            let byAlbumCell = UINib(nibName: "AlbumCell",bundle: nil)
            self.tableView.register(byAlbumCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "byAlbumCell")
            let albumCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "byAlbumCell", for: indexPath) as! AlbumCell
//            albumCell.configureCell(choosenAlbum: filterViewModel.getSelectedAlbum())
            albumCell.selectionStyle = .none
            
            filterViewModel.getAlbum = { selectedAlbum in
                albumCell.configureCell(choosenAlbum: selectedAlbum)
            }
            
            
            return albumCell
            
            
        case 5:
            let albumPickerCell = UINib(nibName: "AlbumsPickerTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
            self.tableView.register(albumPickerCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "albumPickerCell")
            let albumsPicker = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "albumPickerCell", for: indexPath) as! AlbumsPickerTableViewCell
            //            albumsPicker.albumsPickerCellDelegate = self
            albumsPicker.albumsPickerCellDelegate = filterViewModel
            
            
            return albumsPicker
            
            
        default:
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        
    }
    
    
    // MARK: TableViewDelegate Methods:
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
        
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        
        // 1 - We Delete the UIPicker when the user "Deselect" thr row.
        if let datePickerIndexPath = albumsPickerIndexPath,   datePickerIndexPath.row - 1 == indexPath.row {
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [datePickerIndexPath], with: .fade)
            self.albumsPickerIndexPath = nil
            let albumCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! AlbumCell
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
                albumCell.arrowPickerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            }
        } else {
            // 2
            //            if let datePickerIndexPath = albumsPickerIndexPath {
            //                tableView.deleteRows(at: [datePickerIndexPath], with: .fade)
            //            }
            
            let albumCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! AlbumCell
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
                albumCell.arrowPickerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
            }
            albumsPickerIndexPath = indexPathToInsertDatePicker(indexPath: indexPath)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [albumsPickerIndexPath!], with: .fade)
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        }
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
        if indexPath.row == 4  {
            return indexPath
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}


extension FilterTableViewController: DatesTableViewCellDelegate {
    
    func didButtonFromPressed() {
        let pickerController = CalendarPickerViewController(
            baseDate: Date(),
            selectedDateChanged: { [weak self] date in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                
                //          self.item.date = date
                
                
//                self.filterModel.startDate = date
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0)], with: .fade)
            })
        present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
    func didButtonToPressed() {
        //TODO: Present our custom calendar
        let calendarController = CalendarPickerViewController(
            baseDate: Date(),
            selectedDateChanged: { [weak self] date in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                
                
//                self.filterModel.endDate = date
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0)], with: .fade)
            })
        self.present(calendarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Here's my Model:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit



class FilterModel {
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    
    var byActivity: String = ""
    var postType: [String] = []
    var hashTags: [String] = []
    var startDate: Date = Date()
    var endDate: Date = Date()
    var album: String = ""
    
    
    init() {
        // First we need to fetch the data from the local storeage and insert into the vars:
        
        self.fetchData()
    }
    
    
    deinit {
        //Second we need to save the data in the local storeage:
        self.saveData()
        print("Im being deinited")
    }
    
    
    
    // MARK: - UserDefaults Section:
    //Fetch - Retrieve from NSUserDefaults(local):
    func fetchData() {
        self.byActivity = userDefaults.string(forKey: k.UserDefaultsSaveKeys.byActivitySaveKey) ?? self.byActivity
        self.postType = userDefaults.stringArray(forKey: k.UserDefaultsSaveKeys.postTypeSaveKey) ?? self.postType
        self.hashTags = userDefaults.stringArray(forKey: k.UserDefaultsSaveKeys.hashTagsSaveKey) ?? self.hashTags
        self.startDate = userDefaults.object(forKey: k.UserDefaultsSaveKeys.startDateSaveKey) as? Date ?? self.startDate
        self.endDate = userDefaults.object(forKey: k.UserDefaultsSaveKeys.endDateSaveKey) as? Date ?? self.endDate
        self.album = userDefaults.string(forKey: k.UserDefaultsSaveKeys.albumSaveKey) ?? self.album
        
        
        
        print("Checking \(userAlreadyExist(kUsernameKey: k.UserDefaultsSaveKeys.albumSaveKey) )")
    }
    
    
    //Save - Save to local(NSUserDefaults):
    func saveData() {
        userDefaults.set(self.byActivity, forKey: "SavedByActivity")
        userDefaults.set(self.postType, forKey: "SavedPostType")
        userDefaults.set(self.hashTags, forKey: "SavedHashTags")
        userDefaults.set(self.startDate, forKey: "SavedStartDate")
        userDefaults.set(self.endDate,forKey: "SavedEndDate")
        userDefaults.set(self.album,forKey: k.UserDefaultsSaveKeys.albumSaveKey)
    }
    
    
    
    //Testing function
    func userAlreadyExist(kUsernameKey: String) -> Bool {
        return userDefaults.object(forKey: kUsernameKey) != nil
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like writing a general save method in your FilterModel:

```
func saveValue(_ value: Any, forKey key: String) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: key)
}
```

Then call it in your delegate methodes like that:

```
func didButtonToPressed() {
   //TODO: Present our custom calendar
   let calendarController = CalendarPickerViewController(
       baseDate: Date(),
       selectedDateChanged: { [weak self] date in
          guard let self = self else { return }
          self.filterModel.saveValue(date, forKey: "SavedEndDate")
          self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0)], with: .fade)
        })
   self.present(calendarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Make sure that the key you are using to save the values are the same as the key you are retrieving it.

Also saving data in deinit is not a good practice, as deinit have some other purpose, is called when an instance is deallocated to free memory. And this is not happening immediately after a view is disappeared from the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    filterViewModel.fetchData()
}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisppear(animated)
    filterViewModel.saveData()
}
```

Comment: Tried that aswell (even d-bugged) but it doesnt call that method :\ I mean the fetching part is not the problem cause its fetching the data once the object is inited, its all about the saving to userdefaults thats the problem :\

Comment: I'm not sure when you want the model to be updated

Comment: Let me explain you what I'm doing, Im having a view-model controller which updates the model using delegates(for exmaple that album thing is being updated from a uipicker which sends the data using delegates), now I want to update my model and save it locally using UserDefaults the thing is I dont know where to save it, i tried doing that inside the viewWillDisappear but it doesnt work, however the fetch works cause i placed it inside the "Init"

Comment: But you don't need it to be saved to UserDefaults technically until the app closes right?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to check if is saved.

```
userDefaults.string (forKey: k.UserDefaultsSaveKeys.albumSaveKey)
```

if it remains, then check the keys:

```
userDefaults.set (self.byActivity, forKey: "SavedByActivity")
userDefaults.set (self.postType, forKey: "SavedPostType")
userDefaults.set (self.hashTags, forKey: "SavedHashTags")
userDefaults.set (self.startDate, forKey: "SavedStartDate")
userDefaults.set (self.endDate, forKey: "SavedEndDate")
```